# Error in network definition: bond0: interface 'eno2' is not defined

Tags: 20.04, netplan, network-bonding

I get this error when trying to netplan apply. eno2 exists but netplan says it's not defined.

---

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    bonds:
            bond0:
                    interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
                    addresses: [192.168.0.104/24]
                    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
                    parameters:
                            mode: 802.3ad
                    nameservers:
                            addresses: [192.168.0.2]
                    dhcp4: false
                    optional: true
```

---

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.12/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 6374sec preferred_lft 6374sec
    inet6 fe80::ae1f:6bff:fefc:a9da/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the device exists at the kernel level, you must provide config in your netplan yaml defining it for netplan use.  Otherwise netplan will not assume the kernel device of this name is the one you want.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1: {}
    eno2: {}
  bonds:
        bond0:
                interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
                addresses: [192.168.0.104/24]
                gateway4: 192.168.0.1
                parameters:
                        mode: 802.3ad
                nameservers:
                        addresses: [192.168.0.2]
                dhcp4: false
                optional: true
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find that answer anywhere. Worked perfect.